# C# store an integer input in class for recall later?

Tags: c#, input, console

I want to store the integer input from a user as an instance level variable so that I can recall it at a later time

So far in Class.cs I have:

```
namespace home
{
    internal class Class
    {

        public string id;
        

        public Class()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("please enter ID");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            int id;
            Int32.TryParse(input, out id);
        }
    }
}
```

And then in program.cs:

```
using home; 
Class object1 = new Class();
Console.WriteLine(object1.id);
```

This allows the user to input the number, however, it does not print the number afterwards.

I have managed to recall a string input such as a name, I just cannot get it to recall a number input, so everything works fine except for the number being saved and displayed at a later time. If I put `Console.WriteLine(id);` in the class.cs then it will display it, but obviously it's just displaying the input and not really storing it.

Comment: The code you show is not real c# code. It wont compile , its not even close. Can you please post the actual code you have tried

Comment: It does compile, but sure, I've added the full class code to help understand the formatting

Comment: Where do you set the string field `id`? You set a local int variable `id`, but never the string field `id`.

Comment: That's actually a left over from using int id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Which I used before changing it to the .TryParse because of code I read here while research this issue. The string is part of the problem I'm having in not knowing how to save the user input for recall later

Comment: This question is not very clear because you didn't describe the expected use flow, the code itself is breaking well established patterns which indicates that you haven't done the basic introduction into c# which means our responses are likely to be hard for you to understand. Please try HackerRank.com for a crash course on c# in their 30 days challenge or seek help on sites like codementor.io This is simply not the right forum for the level of support and guidance that you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saving the result of the TryParse call in the "int id" variable which is declared inside the Class constructor and therefor released once the constructor finishes executing. To fix your code, you should be saving your id in the "string id" field declared in the Class class.

If you want to access a member variable ( variable declared in a class ) that shares its name with a local variable ( variable declared in a method ) you have to prepend it with "this."

Now I'm not sure if you meant to declare this as a string, but if you did you can just do this

```
internal Class()
{

    public string id;

    public Class()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("please enter ID");
       id = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

If you meant to declare it as an int you can instead do this

```
internal Class()
{

    public int id;

    public Class()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("please enter ID");
       string id = Console.ReadLine();
       this.id = int.Parse(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your use of "this.id = int.parseInt(id);" What is 'this'? Could you write it in a way I can copy/paste so I can run it and understand? I am getting errors on that line, 
'int' does not contain def for 'parseint' AND ALSO
unassigned local variable 'id'. 
Thanks.

Comment: That's my fault. I mistook it for the way it's done in another language. It's fixed now. "this" is a C# keyword that lets you explicitly reference member variables or methods of the object you're in. We only need to use it because we have a local variable  ("string id") with the same name as the member variable we're trying to access. If we renamed "string id" to something like "string stringId" we could simply do "id = int.Parse(stringId)" in the last line.

Comment: Perfect thanks. This works now. I'll learn more about 'this' now that I've used it. I appreciate your approach and help.

Comment: @windsy Note that you will now get a `FormatException` if `id` doesn't contain a valid integer. I would suggest combining this approach with your `int.TryParse` code to avoid such an error.